# looping through a custom message in ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, array, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a custom message and it has string array(can be called a list)
As I need to iterate through the string array, there is no built in dir that helps with it.
Whenever I try to run a for loop on it, the error says "Custom_Message object is not iterable.
Also I can not use any split or iter stuff on it since its not iterable.
Any idea how to iterate through a custom message.

My Custom_Message file is like this:

```
string[] custom_msg
```

The coding environment is python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343595/looping-through-a-custom-message-in-ros-kinetic/) by [mustafa404](https://answers.ros.org/users/51580/mustafa404/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Whenever I try to run a for loop on it, the error says "Custom_Message object is not iterable.

Plain message objects are indeed not iterable.

> Also I can not use any split or iter stuff on it since its not iterable.

Again, expected.

> Any idea how to iterate through a custom message.
>
> My `Custom_Message` file is like this:

> ```
> string[] custom_msg
> ```

The iterable here is `custom_msg`, not the message object itself (it's unfortunate you've given your message *type* the same name as the only field it contains, that makes this less obvious).

So to iterate over the list contained in `custom_msg` (note: the *field*, not the message object itself), you'd do something like this (in a callback called `my_callback(..)` and the only argument it gets is a `Custom_Message` *instance* called `msg`):

```
def my_callback(msg):
    for the_msg in msg.custom_msg:
        # do something with 'the_msg' here
```

Finally: I'd recommend giving a better name to your message *type*. `Custom_Message` does not convey any information as to what sort of information it contains, and also does not give any clues as to how to interprete the data in it. `custom_msg` as a field name is of course also not really a good idea.

Try to use the field name to give information on what sort of messages are in there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-08**:
Note that this is not a ROS "thing" really, more likely a misunderstanding how to deal with message data and especially in Python.

What could be confusing is the fact that your calback receives a message instance, not just the `custom_msg` field. The message contains the field, but it's not the same entity.